# plink bash -c skips arguments to first command

Tags: bash, putty, plink

When I combine `plink` with `bash -c`, first command does not receive parameters.

Command:

```
plink -batch myuser@myhost bash -c 'echo one; echo two; echo three'
```

Actual output

```
<empty line>
two
three
```

Expected output

```
one
two
three
```

Any idea what's happening? (workaround is clear: just add echo without params; but I'm more looking for the root cause of such strange behavior)

Answer (score 3):

The entire command line received by an SSH server is *not* passed as individual arguments, like you would expect on a Unix-ish environment – it is always transferred as a single string, which is then passed to `sh -c` (using the user's chosen "login shell").

With both the 'plink' and 'ssh' clients, the multiple arguments specified in the client's command line are simply joined together with spaces, **without preserving the original quoting** (as the client doesn't really know what quoting syntax the remote shell will expect). So your command:

```
plink -batch foo bash -c 'echo one; echo two; echo three'
```

is actually equivalent to:

```
plink -batch foo 'bash -c echo one; echo two; echo three'
```

as the three arguments `bash`, `-c`, and `echo one; echo two; echo three` are joined into a single string without any other processing.

Because the command is already executed through a shell, what's actually run on the server side is:

```
$SHELL -c 'bash -c echo one; echo two; echo three'
```

The user's login shell runs three commands:

1. `bash -c echo one`
2. `echo two`
3. `echo three`

Note that the first command is *not* `bash -c 'echo one'`. Because the original quoting has long ago been lost, it's now two separate arguments.

In that command, only the word `echo` is the actual command argument given to `-c`, while the following word `one` is not – instead it's a positional argument. Without `-c`, bash would expect a script filename at that position, but with `-c` it's just an arbitrary string that becomes the value of `$0`. For example:

```
bash -c 'echo 0=$0, 1=$1, 2=$2' one two three
```

So what happens in your case is that bash assigns the word 'one' to $0, then runs 'echo' without any parameters.

---

To avoid this problem:

1. If any quoting is used, quote the *entire* command as well. For example, if you must run `bash -c...`, you should do something like this:

   ```
   plink -batch foo "bash -c 'echo one; echo two; echo three'"
   ```

   This way the inner quotes will be preserved.
2. To keep things simple, do not use `bash -c` unless you *specifically* want bash. If the user's standard shell is okay, just send the command directly – it will be run through `$SHELL -c` anyway:

   ```
   plink -batch foo 'echo one; echo two; echo three'
   ```

This applies equally to `ssh` as well as `plink`.